# How to view iPhone Safari developer tools on Mac over WiFi?

Tags: safari, mobile-safari

I need to access the JavaScript console/debugger menu from my iPhone on my Mac but I need to test it while the iPhone is not charging.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Connect your iPhone to your Mac via USB
2. Go to Safari on your Mac
3. Mac: Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Show Developer menu in menu bar
4. iPhone: Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Inspector
5. Mac: Safari > Develop > [iPhone Name] > Connect via Network
6. Unplug the iPhone form USB. You should still see it in the menu
7. Go to the website on iPhone Safari
8. On your Mac select the website. A window should open with console, inspect element and a bunch of other developer tools.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tip: Safari should be using the latest versions both on iPhone and Mac otherwise these steps won’t work.